# how to place child divs vertically center in center of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with some child div, I wanted them to align vertically in center of the parent div like a centered column. Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/yX3p9/344/

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="table-body">
        <div class="topchair">
            <div class="chair">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="leftchairs">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="chair">3</div>
                <div class="chair">4</div>
                <div class="chair">5</div>
                <div class="chair">6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div
```

I also tried display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle; But it also didn't work, What should I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We can help you with specific problems with your code, but we're not going to do all the coding for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new in here, i update my question

Comment: That isn't code. show us what you have tried so far to get to your objective, not the bar bones scaffolding of the html that is hold your variables later on.  like @HunterTurner said. we aren't a code writing service. Take a look here to figure out what is expected http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I update the question again, If possible answer please.

Comment: Which `div`s are you trying to vertically align?

Comment: leftchairs child divs i wnat in center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct its this:

```
.chair {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px auto;         <---  Use auto to center element left/right
    background: deepskyblue;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That margin callout, as used with two entries reads (top/bottom   left/right)  If the element has a fixed width, then auto will center it...

Comment: You are just awesome... love you bro. Thank you so much.

Comment: You missed it by just one word.  I didn't have to do much.  Thank you for posting a decent jsfiddle.  Most new folks don't do that very well.